# Customize .git depth for all repositories?

Tags: git, github

Suppose I clone from a 30000 commit repo on GitHub. If my understanding is correct, it will copy over all 30000 commits, which can take up a lot of disk space. However, 99% of the time I don't care about 29990 of those commits, since I only need to see the most recent history from `git log`.

I am aware of using `git clone --depth N` in order to only checkout the last N commits, however I'm wondering if there is a way to continually enforce this?

E.g. I checkout the latest 1000 commits. 200 more commits are then made on remote, so the next time I pull, the oldest 200 commits are removed from disk and the new 200 commits are added, so that I only ever store 1000 commits locally.

I don't have a very in-depth understanding of git, so any explanation is very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the initial shallow clone with `git clone --depth 1000` you can continue maintaining the shallow depth using [`git fetch --depth 1000`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---depthltdepthgt).

Please remember that `git fetch` doesn't update the currently checked out branch so you have to do something like `git pull --depth 1000` to update the current branch. Or `git merge origin/master` or `git rebase origin/master`.

You can also do `git reset --hard origin/master`. But let's me remind that `git reset --hard` removes the current uncommitted changes so please be careful.

There is no way to automate depth maintaining. You need to pass `--depth 1000` to any `git clone/fetch/pull` command you run.